# Elastic Search in general

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm completely new to Elastic Search or to searching in general. 
I tried to figure out how it is working but I'm not sure if I understood it right.

Is it right, that I for example get a JSON with my data, I have to index it with elastic search and don't have to care about another database in general? I mean, I don't have to create a database by myself?

I hope I could explain I am struggling with..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, ElasticSearch can not only work without external database but even act as a database system itself in the sense that it may store the original JSON document that has been indexed. You can retrieve all the data you are sending to the server when the document has been found either by search query or by its ID as in normal key->value document database. The data is available in [_source](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/mapping/source-field.html) field. This is not necessary for indexing and searching, and can be turned off for storage space conservation, but is turned on by default.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Just send your document as a JSON structure and Elasticsearch will index it and will make it searchable.

Question is: where does this doc come from?
Is it from Twitter? From a database? From a user interface?
To help you gathering these docs, you can use Elasticsearch Rivers.